Flink State Processor API with Windowed CoGroup and Unaligned Checkpoints

How can I use the Flink State Processor API to process the state of a windowed CoGroup (or Join) function? The documentation does not give such an example.
Is there a way to use the Flink State Processor API to process unaligned checkpoints?



Not sure this is doable.
No, this isn't possible. (In general, the on-the-wire serializer needn't be the same as the state serializer. Unaligned checkpoints can include copies of inflight data that the state processor API can't deserialize.)

See the table in the docs showing the capabilities and limitations of checkpoints vs savepoints for more info on what's possible with the state processor API.

Regarding "Unaligned checkpoints can include copies of inflight data that the state processor API can't deserialize." Can you explain why this is the case? Is this because of endianness?

The state processor API only knows about the state serializer. It has no knowledge of the serializer used by the network stack.
